# How do you apply css transforms to Flash?

Tags: css, css-transforms

I would like to be able to transform youtube videos but it only seems to work in Chrome and Opera. I thought I had this working in Safari but maybe not. The basic problem can be understood like this:

```
iframe { 
    transform:rotateX(-25deg), rotateY(-25deg);
}

<iframe src="myurl"></iframe>
```

[image]

A fiddle is available [here](http://jsfiddle.net/MRZcU/) if you want to see the problem in action (just use the rotateX,Y,Z sliders. the others arent setup for this context).

Comment: I don't see a problem: it works in IE, Firefox, and Safari for iPad too.

Comment: Pavlo! I just learned Apple isn't making new versions of Safari for Windows. I'm on 5.1.7 and Safari is already on 6.

Answer (score 0):

apple stopped updating safari on windows. this works on an up to date version of safari.